# Training's & certifications on Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

We are actually looking for Training's by Apache foundation on CAMEL framework. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, some of the main Camel developers are RedHat employees. RedHat also offers professional Camel support for enterprises.

Camel is part of the Fuse suite at RedHat, therefore you could check out [the Camel trainings of RedHat](https://www.redhat.com/de/services/training/all-courses-exams?f%5B0%5D=taxonomy_product%3ARed%20Hat%20Fuse). There is actually a Camel certification course.

I don't think the Apache foundation offers courses and trainings.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.redhat.com/en/services/certification/rhcs-camel-development

A Red Hat Certified Specialist in Camel Development is able to create and maintain enterprise integration services based on Red Hat® Fuse, Camel, and APIs.